# Center aligning a CheckboxField

Tags: blackberry

I have a CheckboxField that is center aligned using the code below:

```
reminderCheckbox = new CheckboxField(res.getString(OPT_OUT_REMINDER_OFF), false, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
reminderCheckbox.setPadding(getRelativePixels(10), 0, getRelativePixels(15), 0);
add(reminderCheckbox);

private int getRelativePixels(int size) {
    int displaySize = Display.getWidth();

    if (displaySize == 480)
        return size;

    double relativeSize = (double) size / 480.0;
    return (int) (relativeSize * displaySize);
}
```

getRelativePixels() is just to adjust the padding on different resolutions.

My problem is, the CheckboxField is appearing in the center on the simulator but is left aligned on the phone (Bold 9700, running OS 5)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

reminderCheckbox = new CheckboxField(res.getString(OPT_OUT_REMINDER_OFF), false);

hfm.add(reminderCheckbox);

add(hfm);
```